# Sass responsive grids. From 3 column layout (PC) to 2 column layout (Ipad)

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

Fist time using Sass. I have a 3 column layout, would like to change this to 2 column layout when user is on Ipad.

Layout PC
[left sidebar][content][right sidebar]

Layout Ipad
[ left  sidebar ]  [content]
[right sidebar]

```
<div id="main-wrapper">
   <div id="sidebar-left"></div>
   <main id="main-content"></div>
   <aside id="sidebar-right"></aside>
</div>

#sidebar-right {
   @include span(last 4 of 16); 
}

#sidebar-left {
   @include span(first 4 of 16); 
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you explain a bit more. What mixin or library are you using?

Comment: Unless you have a Sass->CSS compilation issue, **only post the compiled CSS**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use media queries to achieve this effect. [More about Media Queries](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)
All you need is knowing the breakpoints for the iPad domensions where the CSS styles should change.

For example if can be at 768px (realistically higher, but lets use that for example)

```
    <div id="main-wrapper">
       <div id="sidebar-left"></div>
       <main id="main-content"></div>
       <aside id="sidebar-right"></aside>
    </div>

// For devices with resolution up to 768
    @media screen and (max-width: 768px)
    { 
       #sidebar-right {
           @include span(last 4 of 16); 
        }
    }
// For devices with resolution above 768
    @media screen and (min-width: 769px)
    { 
        #sidebar-left {
           @include span(first 4 of 16); 
        }
    }
```

If you want to take advantage of using Sass, you can also use the media queries as Mixins, making your life a lot easier, like this:

```
// Scss syntax
@mixin Query_small{
    @media screen and (max-width: 768px){
        @content
    }
}

@mixin Query_large{
    @media screen and (min-width: 769px){
        @content
    }
}

// Sass Syntax
=Query_small
    @media screen and (max-width: 768px)
        @content

=Query_large
    @media screen and (min-width: 769px)
        @content
```